# Position elements over scrollbar

Tags: html, css

How can I place an element over a scroll bar?  In the codepen example, I'm trying to get the white circles over the scrollbar.  Hopefully without setting their positions to absolute.

https://codepen.io/Pricebuster/pen/BmNQgY

```
    <div id="top" class="container topContainer">
     <div class="tile" >a</div>
     <div class="tile" >i</div>
     <div class="tile" >u</div>
     <div class="tile" >e</div>
     <div class="tile" >o</div>  
   </div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Scrollbars are handled by the browser and you can only have little effect on them.

Comment: `hint:use z-index`

Comment: Even `position: absolute` not help you.. because when you scroll right or left circle not going with scroll.